# Count and group individual values in a Dataframe of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe named df that looks like the one below. I have a column of arrays and I want to count the frequency of all values in the array. I would like to group these counts based on the "Group" column if possible as well. The arrays don't have to be the same length.

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | [v1, v2] |
| a | [v1, v3] |
| b | [v2, v3] |

When I call `df.groupby('Group')['Value'].value_counts()` I get the following output:

| Group | Value | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | [v1, v2] | 1 |
| a | [v1, v3] | 1 |
| b | [v2, v3] | 1 |

However, I really want to treat each value in the array uniquely as part of the count. In other words, I am looking for an output like this.

| Group | Value | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | [v1] | 2 |
| a | [v2] | 1 |
| a | [v3] | 1 |
| b | [v2] | 1 |
| b | [v3] | 1 |

How can I achieve this? Maybe some sort of flattening? I'm not sure if flattening would break my ability to group them though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the arrays in the `value` column actually arrays or are they strings - e.g., `['v1', 'v2']` or `"[v1, v2]"`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` as edit to the question?

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity! Was having trouble getting StackOverflow to accept my formatting. The `value` column contains arrays of strings ie. `['v1', 'v2']`. With that being said, looks like user mozway's solution works! Going to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a list in "Value":

```
(df.explode('Value')
   .value_counts()
   .reset_index(name='Freq')
)
```

Or:

```
(df.assign(Freq=1)
   .explode('Value')
   .groupby(['Group', 'Value'], as_index=False)
   .sum()
)
```

Or:

```
(df.explode('Value')
   .groupby(['Group', 'Value'], as_index=False)
   .agg(Freq=('Value', 'size'))
)
```

*NB. If you have strings, add `.str[1:-1].str.split(r',\s*')` before the `explode`.*

Output:

```
  Group Value  Freq
0     a    v1     2
1     a    v2     1
2     a    v3     1
3     b    v2     1
4     b    v3     1
```

Comment: Options two and three got the job done! Thanks a bunch! You are amazing. Any idea how to sort the frequencies in descending order for each group?

Comment: If option 1 didn't work this might mean that you have extra columns? Try to slice `[['Group', 'Value']]` before `explode` and you'll get the values in descending order